# How do I create a function after every loop in a while section?

Tags: python, function, while-loop

Ok, I hope I will say it in the less confunsing way. In this python script the user can send a certain input and the script will repeat n times, I wanted to make a loop that every time is made register another input, everytime now he is replacing the input of the function but I want it to create another one. Here is the code.

```
while (escolha!='5'):
    print("""Welcome to Do it For Me
    Insert your Input in order.
    1- Click
    2- Hotkey
    3- Write
    5- RUN
    Resposta: """) 
    escolha = input('')
    
    
    if (escolha=='1'):
        print('It will start a countdown in your screen, please leave your mouse at the wanted place.')
        time.sleep(5)
        print('5')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('4')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('3')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('2')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('1')
        localclick=pyautogui.position()
        print(localclick) 
        def click():
            pyautogui.click(localclick)
        queue.enqueue(click)    
   
    if (escolha=='2'):
        print("Type your hotkey. Ex: alt+tab+ [3 keys maximum]")
        my_var = input("")
        my_var = my_var.split('+')
        def hotchave():
            pyautogui.hotkey(str(my_var[0]),str(my_var[1]),str(my_var[2]))
        queue.enqueue(hotchave)
        
    if (escolha=='3'):
        write=input('What will be written?: ')
        def escrever():
            pyautogui.write(write)
            pyautogui.press('Enter')
        queue.enqueue(escrever)
        
else:
    print('you choose RUN')
    while(stvez<=numvez): 
        print('foi')
        queue.front()()
        stvez= stvez+1
```

Comment: I tried to understand your problem and I read the question several times. But I cannot understand it. Can you improve the question a bit? Maybe provide some examples?

Comment: Is the indentation of the `else`-block at the end correct?

Comment: Yes! Sorry I really had some difficulty putting the problem in text. I'm going to give an example, If you put `while (condition): var=input('what's the var?)` and then `list.append(var)` the list will not an append a different input every loop. It will just append it again and change the variable that is inside it. I want to append a different input every loop. Really sorry for the mess.

Comment: Yes, the indentation is not the problem in this case.

Comment: Well, I read your code several times and I still couldn't understand it. From what I've understood, you are trying to automate some tasks, like clicking, typing, and this sort of stuff. Imagine I'm a user, what can I do with your code?? What is it's functionality?